# Вывод информации из двух массивов одинаковой размерности Jinja2

Tags: циклы, jinja2

есть массив информации (a), в нем есть 2 массива информации одинаковой размерности (b, d). Мне нужно вывести их элементы в одну строку:
(b0-d0)
(b1-d1)
...
(bn-dn)

Есть следующий код в html:

```
{% for a1 in a.b %}
   {{ loop.index }}-
   {{ a1 }}-
   {{ a.b }}-
   {{ a.d.a1 }}--
   {{ a.d.loop.index }}--
{% endfor %}
```

Вывод вот такой:
[image: Вывод кода]

Т.е. по какой-то причине loop.index пуст и обращение через переменную ничего не выдает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не смог понять почему loop.index был пустым, но решил все следующим образом:

Было сделано 2 массива, оба содержат параметры-ключи. 
Второй массив также содержит необходимые параметры, только, если ранее данные, которые нужно было вывести в одну строчку передавались массивом, то теперь передаются по элементам.

Т.е. выглядело это примерно так:

```
a = [cn1, cn2]
a1 = [{'name1': a[0], 'elmas1': mas[0], 'elmas2': mas1[0]},,
      {'name1': a[0], 'elmas1': mas[1], 'elmas2': mas1[1]}
      {'name1': a[1], 'elmas1': mas[1], 'elmas2': mas1[1]}]
```

В html заходил через for в массив a, а после в массив a1, после чего сравнивал кодовые имена (это сделано, для разделения вывода по этим самым ключам (разделение было изначально, проблемы были с выводом в одну строчку)).

Наверняка можно было сделать лучше, если знаете как - пишите, буду благодарен.